# php multiple sql queries into one table

Tags: php, sql-server

i need insert multiple sql queries into one table in specific td. How i can do it? i have this one query, which working fine :

```
$sql = "SELECT Code, Name, Specification, Specification2, X_pozicane_u FROM StoreCards";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
```

and output :

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Code'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Specification'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Specification2'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['X_pozicane_u'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

How can i set sql2 and insert it to specific TD?

thank you

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want it to look like?

Comment: yes of course - as i show, i have one sql and result i inserting into td . and i need more different sql queries and also inserting it into td of same table. how i can do it?

Comment: So what is sql2?  There is no code or mention of it anywhere except you want to set and insert it.

Comment: sql2 i mean : $sql2 = "SELECT Quantity, Name, Code FROM Stores";

Comment: Is there some common key between the table Stores and StoreCards, if so you would be better using a JOIN in the query and fetching all the data in one go.

Comment: this is the problem ... its database of ERP system, and have some tables without keys to other

Comment: How are you supposed to fetch this other data then, your code will simply fetch all Stores records.

Comment: and when i using for eg this query : $sql = "SELECT sc.Code, sc.Name, sc.Specification, sc.Specification2, f.Name FROM StoreCards sc
left join firms f on f.id = sc. X_pozicane_u ";
give me result of bad td rows like before

Comment: because first sql result which working is here : https://i.imgur.com/LgU5NJf.png is this sql : $sql = "SELECT Code, Name, Specification, Specification2, X_pozicane_u FROM StoreCards";

Comment: and this is with join : https://i.imgur.com/fm2gsKY.png sql : $sql = "SELECT sc.Code, sc.Name, sc.Specification, sc.Specification2, f.Name FROM StoreCards sc left join firms f on f.id = sc. X_pozicane_u ";

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149985/discussion-between-martin-jasek-and-nigel-ren).

Answer (score -2):

Try with this:

```
<?php
$sql  = "SELECT Code, Name, Specification, Specification2, X_pozicane_u FROM StoreCards";
$stmt = $conn->query($sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Code'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Specification'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Specification2'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['X_pozicane_u'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Not sure what this is for at all?  How does this answer the original question?